# matching value by non-unique id and minimum date difference

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, left-join, rsqlite

I'm using sqlite through the RSQLite package in R.

I have two tables: 
Table 1 has important columns 'PERMCO' and 'Reporting_Period'.
('Reporting_Period' is an integer date)

Table 2 has important columns 'PERMCO' and 'date'.
('date' is an integer date)

I want to do a left join with table 1 as the left table.
Thing is that 'PERMCO' is not unique (row-wise, many duplicates) in the second table.

For a given row of table 1, I want the match from the second table to be the row from table 2 with matching PERMCO that is closest in absolute date to 'Reporting_Period' in the first table.

Not really sure how to do this...

Thank you

Comment: what have you done so far? code/query?

Comment: add  sample query and expected output

Answer (score 0):

The Idea is a correlated subquery to get the closest day in table2 from Reporting_Period in table1

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.permco = t2.permco
WHERE ABS(t2."date" - t1.Reporting_Period) = (SELECT MIN(ABS("date" - t1.Reporting_Period) )
                                  FROM table2 
                                  WHERE permco = t1.permco
                                  )
     OR t2.permco IS NULL --because you want a left join
;
```

I'm not familier with Sqlite, so you may need to change the query to subtract the two date.